# djangocms installer Operational Error

Tags: django-cms

After running djangocms installer I am getting this error:

Exception Value:
no such table: cms_urlconfrevision

I'm using sqlite default db. I selected stable for my django version. I've tried installing this numerous times and keep getting the same error. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hello, which version of djangocms-installer? also can you post the exact command you ran on the installer?

Comment: 0.9.3. I am following instructions here: http://stationinthemetro.com/2016/06/26/install-django-cms-on-webfaction